# JSF 2.2(Mojarra 2.2.0) Primefaces Issue - While clicking on download button, application is throwing out to sessionExpired page

Tags: authentication, session, primefaces, listener, jsf-2.2

### Here is a snippet of SupportingDocs.xhtml code

```
        <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s" styleClass="blue-button" actionListener="#{entityType.downloadDFile}">
            <f:attribute name="selectedFile" value="#{supportingDoc[column['supportingDocument.downloadlink.column']]}" />
        </p:commandButton>
```

When clicking on Download button, it is downloading file perfectly but in the same time it is logging out as well.

Here is some pointers which I have got while debugging the application.

1. Click "Download" button
2. It calls loginFilter ->doFilter()
3. then it calls loginController -> destroySession()
4. then it calls sessionListener -> sessionDestroyed()
5. then it creates new session by calling sessionListener ->sessionCreated()
6. then loginFilter -> doFilter()

Comment: The loginController and filter is **your** code, so check there why it thinks it need to logout. Impossible for us to help.

Comment: There was java script which was destroying the session. After commenting that code, it worked fine....Thank you!

Comment: javascript client side destroying the session??? Did not think you could do that (unless it removes the cookie)

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   //deleteSessionRemoteCommand();  //After commenting this, it worked as expected. Yet to see the impact of this comment.
   return;
  };
 </script>